# Does anyone know if any of the books below address mathematical analysis with measure theory?

Tags: measure-theory, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a real analysis book that covers measure theory and I've been recommended Folland's or Royden's books, but their price is quite high and I was wondering if any of the books below would serve as a cheaper substitute.

Theory of Functions of Real Variables by Lawrence M. Graves;

Real Variables with Basic Metric Space Topology by Robert B Ash;

Theory of Functions of a Real Variable by I.P. Natanson;

Real Analysis by Gabriel Klambauer;

Nonstandard Analysis by Alain M. Robert;

Foundations of Analysis by David F. Belding and Kevin J. Mitchell;

Foundations of Mathematical Analysis by Richard Johnsonbaugh and W. E. Pfaffenberger;

Mathematical Analysis by Tom M. Apostol;

Elementary Real and Complex Analysis by Georgi E. Shilov;

Foundations of Modern Analysis by Avner Friedman;

Real Analysis by Norman B. Haaser;

Introductory Real Analysis by A. N. Kolmogorov;

Introduction to Analysis by Maxwell Rosenlicht.

Comment: Rudin's RCA is the best, in my opinion.

Comment: Sheldon Axler provides a free electronic version of Measure, Integration & Real Analysis at his web site.

Comment: Though perhaps more focused on measure and integration theory, I find Donald L. Cohn's "Measure Theory" to be very clear. A pdf version online can be found e.g. [here](https://ia802500.us.archive.org/22/items/ittushu-3856/Measure_Theory.pdf).

Comment: Measure theory is not covered by Ash or Shilov. It is covered by Kolmogorov (which is unsurprising; after all, Kolmogorov was the one who built the foundation of probability theory on measure theory), but the translators of his book remarked that Kolmogorov’s approach, which uses sigma ring rather than sigma algebra, may make things difficult. Apostol has a chapter on Lebesgue integration, but IIRC the mathematical derivation is based on simple functions (so I guess it follows the Daniell integral approach), not measure theory.